# Best possible specs for a MEMS mic in 2014?

Tags: audio, microphone, component-selection, mems, mems-microphone

I want to use the best MEMS mic that's on the market today (June 2014) in terms of audio quality.  Since I know that "shopping" questions are forbidden, I'll phrase it like this:

What are considered top-of-the-line specs for the best MEMS mics currently available, in terms of **signal-to-noise ratio**, **sensitivity**, and other key specs?  Is the state of the art better or worse for **analog mics compared to digital mics**?

Thank you!  Please let me know if you have a suggestion for how to phrase this question better instead of just downvoting.

Comment: "Best possible" would be a theoretical/academic question. "Best available" would be a shopping question; there's no way around that. Which is it?

Comment: Best possible in mass production today ;)  Not asking about theory, but about manufacturability in practice at the current MEMS process node. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think questions like that are well suited for this website.

Comment: What website is the right place to go? EDAboard?